# Javascript Object.defineProperty property has same name with method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to js world and find jquery declares many properties as methods which make me very uncomfortable.Such as `$("#foo").parent()` which i think should be a property.

I know that js can also define property so i want to try redefine these method to corresponding property.

```
Object.defineProperty($.fn,"parent",
        {
            get:function () {
                return this.parent()
            },
            configurable:false,
            enumerable:true
        });
```

then i can use it like this `$("#foo").parent`

but i got a stackoverflow

```
jqueryplus.js:180 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at n.fn.init.get [as parent] (jqueryplus.js:180)
    at n.fn.init.get [as parent] (jqueryplus.js:181)
    at n.fn.init.get [as parent] (jqueryplus.js:181)
    at n.fn.init.get [as parent] (jqueryplus.js:181)
    at n.fn.init.get [as parent] (jqueryplus.js:181)
    at n.fn.init.get [as parent] (jqueryplus.js:181)
    at n.fn.init.get [as parent] (jqueryplus.js:181)
    at n.fn.init.get [as parent] (jqueryplus.js:181)
    at n.fn.init.get [as parent] (jqueryplus.js:181)
    at n.fn.init.get [as parent] (jqueryplus.js:181)
```

What's happening here? In my mind, it should be possible for variables/property  and methods to have the same name which i'm familiar with in other language such as c#,kotlin...

Comment: Since you are new, you should embrace the new JS idioms instead of trying to change them. Notice that the [jQuery `parent` method](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) takes an optional parameter, which your getter would not be capable of.

Comment: "*it should be possible for variables/property and methods to have the same name*" - nope, that's not how JavaScript works. They live in the same "namespace" - and methods are really just normal properties which have a function object as their value. That's why your getter tries to get itself.

Comment: I'd suggest you learn to deal with properties as methods. This is a rather large waste of time which is just going to create more problems than it solves.

Comment: thanks for your advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining `Object.parent` to call himself, that's an infinite recursive loop.

The reason why jQuery defines functions to get properties is that it computes dynamic values at runtime, using an oldish coding style (getters and setters exist only from [ES5.1 specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)). maybe what you could do is create shortcuts for those properties (`Object.prototype.par`instead of `parent`), but there's no effort on doing that IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

here this.parent() is make calling function recursively. so give some other name to ur defined function something like getparent `Object.defineProperty($.fn,"getparent",` call this as `$("#foo").getparent`